# Understanding hidden fields

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I was wondering if you guys could help me understand hidden fields, since I don't think I am getting them to work.

On the aspx page I have:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidVal" value="" runat="server" />
```

On a button click I have a JavaScript function called

```
<button type="button" id="search" onclientclick="search_click()">Search</button>
```

With the function being

```
function search_click() {
    document.getElementById('hidVal').Value = "1";

    <% save(); %>
}
```

In aspx.cs I have a function that does this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\fgreene\Desktop\savedAdresses.txt", true))
{
    file.WriteLine(hidVal.Value);
}
```

After clicking the button I look into the file and there is no change.
Is my approach correct or am I not understanding how this works?

Comment: it looks like you want your `search_click()` function to set the value on the client, and then call a server-side method. Is this right? (this is not going to work)

Comment: Warning, server side control's ID are not actual client side IDs. You should write : `document.getElementById('<%= hidVal.ClientID %>').Value = "1";` to produce, at render time, the actual ID of the hidden field

Comment: Looks like you are attempting to do a server side method <% save(); %> on the client (javascript).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reference the client ID of the hidden field, which is probably not `hidVal`, as the actual client side ID generated in the HTML will be based on the parent control's naming container.  There's two ways to fix this.  First, you could make the client ID *static* on the control (which basically tells ASP.NET *make the ID exactly what I said.*):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidVal" value="" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Second, you can look up the ClientID property from the server when you generate your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('<%= hidVal.ClientID %>').Value = "1";
```

This would render out the actual client ID directly in the JavaScript code.  Either approach is probably fine, but the second one would only work if the JavaScript is embedded directly in your ASPX file and not in a static .JS file.

**Calling server side methods:**

The second part of your question is about calling server side code when the button is pressed.  You should do this by attaching an `OnClick` handler to your button:

```
<button runat="server" id="BtnSearch" onclientclick="search_click()" OnClick="btnSearch_Click">Search</button>
```

When the button is pressed, the page will be posted back and the `btnSearch_Click` event handler will be called.  You'll then be able to handle any server side logic, as well as check the value of your hidden field.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This is only part of the problem; there's also nothing calling back to the server that the button has been pressed and the value updated.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really clear what `save()` was but I guess the intention is to *call* that method when the JavaScript function is called?

Comment: I think that's the intention, and I assume `save` is the function in the .aspx.cs he talks about.

Comment: @Rawling - Updated my answer, though your answer covers it quite well too.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `<% save(); %>` in a JavaScript function in an aspx page causes `save` to be run *when the page is built on the server*, not when the surrounding JavaScript function is called on the client. At this point, the hidden field is empty, so your file gets a blank line written to it. When the user clicks the button, the hidden field is filled, but there's nothing to tell the server that this has happened.

What you need to do instead is something like:

```
// In your aspx, for the javascript function: remove the call to save,
// use the correct ID for the hidden field
function search_click() {
    document.getElementById('<%= hidVal.ClientID %>').Value = "1";
}

// In your aspx in place of the button put
<asp:Button id="search" runat="server"
            onclientclick="search_click(); return true;" onclick="search_click">
    Search
</asp:Button>
// This results in a button that calls the javascript function on click, and
// then posts back to the server saying that the button has been clicked

// In your C#, this function gets called when the client posts back to
// say that the button has been clicked.
public protected void search_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
               @"C:\Users\fgreene\Desktop\savedAdresses.txt", true))
    {
        file.WriteLine(hidVal.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is execute a server side function (save) via a client side call.  This won't work as it is calling save() when the page first loads and then putting the return value (which is probably nothing) into the code where you put

```
<% save(); %>
```

Instead you need your button to fire the save function, but fire your javascript first.  You do this by creating an asp:button (which renders as ) and then adding both an "OnClientClick" (for your javascript) and "OnClick" (for your server side function).

```
<asp:Button id="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="search_click()" text="Search" />
```

Then in your C# code you need the method to be named the same as the OnClick value:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\fgreene\Desktop\savedAdresses.txt", true))
    {
        file.WriteLine(hidVal.Value);
    }
}
```

The easiest way to create your server side function is to double click on the button in design view, as it will add the correct method call for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change hidden field value in both serverside and client side events.

**Change value in client side**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function setvalue() {
            document.getElementById('hidVal').value = "1";
        }
  </script>

  <div>
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hidVal" value="" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="setvalue();" />
  </div>
```

**Change value in serverside**

```
    <div>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hidVal" value="" runat="server" />
        <br />
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>

   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidVal.Value = "1";
    }
```